# picking bits 16 at a time from a binary string and summing and updating the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, sum

i have the following cout<< 1100001011000100110001101100100

i want to pick 16 bits at a time from this and save it to an array in the following manner:

1. save the first 16 bits to the array
2. pick the next 16 bits and add to the same array and save //binary addition
3. pick another 16, if no of bits left <16 padd zero bits after the ones left to make its length 16
   bits and then repeat the addition in 2.
4. at the end of the summing and saving...see if length of array > 16 bits for the last sum...this
   means there was an extra carry bit....padd zero bits to this carry bit this way:
   0000000000000001 (carry bit at 16th position) and add to the final sum in array

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char character;
    int i;
    int m[8];


    cout<<"Please enter a character string: ";
    cin>>character;
    cout<<"You've entered "<<character<<endl; 
    //i entered abcd it gives me 01100001011000100110001101100100 in cout. how should i save this         
    as a continuous array? 
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        m[i]=character%2;
        character = character/2;
    }

    int top, bottom;

    for(bottom=0,top =7; bottom<8; bottom++,top--)
    {
        m[bottom]=m[top];
        cout<<m[top];
    }

    return 0;
     }
```

Comment: i was thinking of using bitset<16> but dont know if thats a very viable approach.how do i apply it on m[top]. m having issues indexing it because m[top] is an 8 bit int array indexing over top itself. i dont know how to save this m[top] to another array of indefinite length. my string is variable...i cant set an array size to save it to or can i?

Comment: `m[top]` is an 8 bit int array? Your post says it's a binary string, it conveys the idea that it's a characters sequence of '0' and '1'. You should edit that. And how long is this array?

Comment: @Filipe: iv corrected it. you're right. 8 bit string appended with 8 zero padded bits. but i want to pick 16bits that is two m[top] at a time.

Comment: can anyone please help me, i cant seem to figure it out.